# Anchos diferentes, en Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

alguien sabe como asignar a una `etiqueta` un determinado ancho, en mobil y otro en desktop. Utilizando la clase de `w-x`

Ejemplo:

```
<main class="row h-50 w-75 mx-auto align-content-end text-center"></main>
```

Quiero qué en mobil, sea un ancho del 100% y en desktop uno del 75%

Comment: Deberías usar el sistema de grillas y columnas, ya que estas utilidades no traen definidas ninguna regla media queries. Revisa: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

En la documentación de [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/) en la sección de "sizing" (Dimensionamiento) puedes ver que no hay clase `w-` para diferentes tamaños de pantalla

Lo que puedes hacer es usar el sistema de [columnas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/) y de esa forma utilizar diferente ancho de columna según el tamaño de tu pantalla

Por ejemplo la combinación de clases `col-md-3 col-6` hace que un elemento (Por ejemplo un `div`) tenga un ancho de 3 columnas en pantallas medianas o superiores y un ancho de 6 columnas para pantallas más pequeñas

Te dejo un ejemplo para que veas como funciona:

```css
.rojo {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.verde{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-6 rojo">
      Primera columna
    </div>
    <div class="col verde">
      Segunda columna
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para ver como cambia el ancho de columna puedes cambiar el tamaño de tu navegador de internet o abrir el inspector de tu navegador (Si usas Chrome puedes oprimir F12)